# Running django custom management commands with supervisord

Tags: django, supervisord

I'd like to use supervisord to run some commands for my Django project but I keep getting the following error:

supervisor.log:

```
2012-05-18 17:52:15,784 INFO spawnerr: can't find command 'source'
```

If I remove the "source" command, the log shows the same error: `can't find command 'python'`.

supervisord.conf excerpt:

```
[program:django]
directory=/home/mf/projects/djangopj/
command=beanstalkd -l 127.0.0.1 -p 11300
command=source /home/mf/virtualenvs/env/bin/activate
command=python manage.py command1
command=python manage.py command2
user=mf
autostart=true
autorestart=true
```

I tried removing the directory and adding the absolute path to the commands but I kept getting the same error.

I run supervisord with the following command:

```
supervisord -c supervisord.conf -l supervisor.log
```

Comment: There is a great project to simplify the process https://github.com/rfk/django-supervisor

Answer (score 9):

The `source` command is only available in `bash`, and the supervisor command is run by `sh`. I would recommend using a script to perform your commands:

**/etc/supervisor/conf.d/my_app.conf**

```
[program:my_app]
command = bash /path/to/app/init.sh
directory = /path/to/app/
user = ubuntu
autostart=true
autorestart=true
```

**/path/to/app/init.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

beanstalkd -l 127.0.0.1 -p 11300
source /home/mf/virtualenvs/env/bin/activate    
python manage.py command1
python manage.py command2
```

The only problem is that supervisor will only have control of the script, not the command(s). If you have a situation where you want supervisor to manage and keep alive a specific process, I would recommend using `exec` in your bash init file, that way supervisor will have control of your process. E.g.

**/path/to/app/init.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash

exec beanstalkd -l 127.0.0.1 -p 11300
```

You may find this useful: http://sjsnyder.com/managing-virtualenv-apps-with-supervisor

Comment: The link is broken, but [there's a copy in the wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20130526045634/http://sjsnyder.com/managing-virtualenv-apps-with-supervisor).

Comment: Recommendation about "exec" helped me. Thanks!